# Drupal search with Gmap and location

Tags: drupal, google-maps, drupal-6, drupal-views

we have drupal 6 project where one separate content type is AUTHOR where we record their name,email, and all location related fields like Zipcode, City, address etc now we want that to create a search form where user can select the Authors type like (English Author, German AUthors fields from Author content type after that user enter the zipcode and select the search range in miles like 1 Mile or 5 miles etc after that when user press the search button it show all the location on google map with custom marker image on right side of that search form

so layout like that

SEARCH FORM (on left) AND Google map with locations (on Right)

Please help me with examples thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) and [GMap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) modules will give you everything you need.